# how to select first item by default and then highlight the selected item in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a app, that displays all items in left side and by default it should highlight the first item and show the item details in rightside view. when user clicks any item in the list it should highlight that item and show the selected item details in right side view.

here is my code (leftside view):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList()| filter:{status: itemType}">
    <div  id="itemRow" ng-click="selectedItem(item)" ng-class="{'active':selectedItemid === item.id}">     
            <div id="itemRowContent">               
                    <div id="itemName" class="appFont"><b>{{item.name}}</b></div>

    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

In controller:

```
 $scope.selectedItem= function(item){
        $scope.selectedItem = item;        
        $scope.selectedItemid = item.id;       
   };
```

Right side view:

```
            <div class="headersInfoRow2"> {{selectedItem.type}}:</div>
            <div class="headersInfoRow2"> {{selectedItem.price}}</div>
            <div class="headersInfoRow3"> {{selectedItem.quantity}}</div> 
 ...
```

...

currently, it is displaying selected item, how to highlight first item and display first item details in right side view by default.then highlight the slected item and display selected item details.

Comment: You should not do: "$scope.selectedItem= function(item){" and then "$scope.selectedItem = item;" You should rename the first one to $scope.selectItem= function(item){

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.

Let's say you have a class `.selected` which is attached to the element which is active; then, you can modify your HTML/Angular code to use the `ng-class` directive.

```
ng-class="{selected: $index==0}"
```

What you've tried is pretty similar, but it needs to be on that track. Try this code and it **should** work.

Comment: where do I add ng-if directive?

Comment: I think @weirdpanda wanted to said `ng-class`. Because `ng-if` does not have sense. You do not want to hide/show something.

Comment: I am so sorry, I got a little confused between the two; I have edited it, I hope it's a little clear now.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have a ternary operator in your `ng-class` checking to see if `$scope.selectedItemid` is undefined. If `$scope.selectedItemid` is undefined check to see if the item is the first in the repeat with [$first](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) property of ng-repeat:

```
ng-class="{'active':selectedItemid==undefined ? $first : selectedItemid === item.id}"
```

Comment: This works to highlight the first one by default and selected one. how do I display first item list in right side?how do I get that object as I am not calling selectIem() function bydefault?

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that part. Is there a reason you aren't initializing `$scope.selectedItem` with the first index of `itemList()`? Because that would solve both issues.

Comment: I used this statemnet in ng-repeat "item in itemList()| filter:{status: itemType}" and itemList is a function calling from service class.I am not sure how to get first object from this itemList() and it has different filters.is there any way to get first object ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $scope.selectedItem works correctly for clicking, as you said it did, just call the function against the first item as part of the initialization of your control or immediately after loading of data. For example, at the bottom of your control file, or at the end of the function that loads data into itemList, call:

```
$scope.selectedItem( itemList[0] );
```